# Auto complete text box in c# datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a data-gird view, and its first cell is student register no. and the cell is auto complete text box.When we focus on any of the data in auto compete text box then corresponding data shown in next cell. How can I do it? Which event is used? My first cell is already an auto complete cell. My requirement is, the auto complete text box contains number of data. when cursor move upward or downward in the auto complete text box(here register.no) the next cell automatically shown student name. For this which event is used?

Comment: I tried in cell value changed,cell leave,cell end edit. But I want output not like that. Register no cell is an auto complete text box. when selection focus any register no. automatically the correspond data shown in next cell.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(3) && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
        {
            dataGridView1[1,(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1)].Value ="Your Value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My requirement is, the auto complete text box contains number of data. when cursor move upward or downward in the auto complete text box(here register.no) the next cell automatically shown student name. For this which event is used?

Comment: you can try cell click event or selection changed event.